# Exercise about differential forms and pull-back: $\omega_p=0$ if and only if $(\omega|_U)_p=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a manifold, $\omega\in\Omega^q(M)$. Let $U\subset M$ be an open subset embedded as manifold in $M$. Let $p\in U$. Show that $\omega_p=0$ if and only if $(\omega|_U)_p=0$.

**Notation**: Let $F:U\to M$ be the inclusion map which is an embedding.
          $F^*:\Omega^*(M)\to\Omega^*(U)$ be its pull-back. We denote $F^*\omega$ by $\omega|_U$.

Suppose $\omega_p =0$. Then $(\omega|_U)_p=(F^*\omega)_p=dF^*_p(\omega_{F(p)})=dF^*_p(\omega_{p})=0$,
where the last equality follows by linearity of $dF^*_p$.

I can't prove the reverse implication. Any suggestion?

Comment: $\omega_p$ is a notation for "$\omega$ evaluated in $p$". $\omega:M\to \Lambda^qT^*M$ is a $q$-differential form.......

Comment: @AdamSaltz I think you didn't read my question carefully! I ask $(\omega|_U)_p=0$,not $\omega|_U=0$. Any concrete help?

Comment: deleting my thoughtless comments

Comment: All that's going on is that $T_pU = T_pM$ (I mean equal, not isomorphic) and $dF_p$ is the identity map.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer.

Does it make sense?
$$
0=(\omega|_U)_p(v_1,\dots,v_q)=(F^*\omega)_p(v_1,\dots,v_q)=dF^*_p(\omega_{F(p)})(v_1,\dots,v_q)=dF^*_p(\omega_{p})(v_1,\dots,v_q)=\omega_p(dF_p(v_1,\dots,v_q))=\omega_p(v_1,\dots,v_q)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Weird notation, usually people write $F^* \omega = \omega \circ F $... which is $\omega | _U$ in this case since $F|_U = id$... Your proof of the one direction doesn't make sense, how did the exterior differential come into play? Nevertheless, note that $F$ is the inclusion map, so we obviously have $F(p) = p$ since $p \in U$. Thus
$$ (F^* \omega)_p = \omega \circ F(p) = (\omega)_p$$
The claim now follows.

Comment: I really don't understand your notation.... My professor tought me $F^*\omega:=dF^*\omega=\omega\circ dF$

Comment: I'd have another read though your text book on pull backs... why would we write $F^* \omega : = d F^* \omega $ ? Have a quick look through: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)

Comment: the definition is the one I posted... I have your definition just in the case $F$ is a linear map between vector spaces

Comment: You can also see pg 136 John Lee "Introduction to smooth manifolds"

Comment: In wikipedia the definition is the same. See "Pullback of differential forms"

Comment: Oh, I see where we're differing on definitions. I use the convention the (with $F: X \to Y$) $dy_i$'s become $d (F_i) = \partial_{x_1} F_i dx_1 + \ldots \partial_{x_n} F_i dx_n$. Notice that since $ F |_U = id$ we'll always have $ d y_i = dx_i$ using this convention. Which gives you the equality I wrote above.

Comment: Your notation is non-standard and only correct (meaningful) in the case of $0$-forms.